# issue on hashtag which created in meatadate

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, metadata, hashtags

I am working in community site SharePoint 2016, when I created hashtag in news feed then click on hashtag I can view all the posts under this hashtag.

but when I create hashtag in metadata , I can use it in discussion but when I click on it , it does not show other posts under same hashtag.

what may be the problem? I have admin of metadata and search service.